# Why is my class variable being re-initialized using cattr_accessor (JRuby, Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

OK, I know this is a bit of a frankenstack, but I am running JRuby on Rails, and I'm relatively new to both.  I'm seeing some behavior that I can't understand, and I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong or if its a problem with my stack.  The basic issue is that it appears that my class attributes are being reinitialized, something that I wouldn't expect to ever happen.

Here's essentially my code

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  cattr_accessor :an_attr
  before_filter :init_an_attr

  def init_an_attr
    if @@an_attr.nil? 
      @@an_attr = {}
    end
    # do some other stuff here
  end
end
```

The problem lies in the fact that every time init_an_attr is called, the condition on the if evaluates to true, and I end up reassigning @@an_attr.

Is that the expected behavior?  If so can you explain why, because to me, the assignment should only happen once.

Comment: FYI the idiom of assigning to a variable only if its nil can be expressed like: `@@an_attr ||= {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails, when running in development mode, classes are not cached. MyController, and all other classes are reloaded on each request.  When running in production, this is not the case - classes are cached.

However, even in production, this variable will be local to a particular application instance - if you're running with two Mongrels, for example, each will have a different version of this variable.

If you want state to be set across multiple requests, consider either using the session, or storing values in your database.  Class variables are really not appropriate for cross-request storage.

Comment: That is quite helpful, the thing I'm trying to preserve is not reasonable to store in either a database or a cookie, as it is a Java object (remember this is JRuby) representing an active connection to a third party system.  Where should I store that?

Comment: In that case, I might actually store it in a class variable.  In development, you'll have to reconnect to the third party service on each request, but in production, each instance of your application will maintain its own connection.  Short of running your own service to maintain the connection, I'm not sure what else you could do.

Comment: @@3rdpartysystem ||= ThirdPartySystem.connection

Comment: using your suggestion of "class caching", I was able to google up the following link that explores the topic... http://zadasnotes.blogspot.com/2011/02/rails-tips-using-class-variables-as.html